# Can't push to TFS Git repository from Eclipse, but command line works fine

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, tfs

I have a Git repository provided by my organization's local instance of TFS. I can checkout, pull, switch branches, etc, all from within Eclipse using the built in capabilities, but when I try to push commits, it times out after 5 minutes with the error:

```
 Can't connect to any repository: ssh://<my redacted project URL> (ssh://<my redacted project URL>: Short read of block.)
```

It works fine from the Git Bash command line, and as mentioned all other commands seem to work fine from Eclipse.

Comment: Look at `workspace/.metadata/.log` file, there may be more details of the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue reported here : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531807

Based on the comments looks like jgit received some corrupt data during push.

Just try David's solution :

> Copying out changed files, deleting project and repo, recloning repo,
>   creating project, copying back in changed files, pushing.  Success.

Basically try to clone a new local repo, tested on my side and it works as expected.